# regex nested quote issue when replacing in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I‘ve got some text like this:

```
prefix:hello1_Th2ere_a3nd_Ther4e
```

and I want to change these text to:

```
prefix:Hello1Th2ereA3ndTher4e
```

and I am trying to run follow command:

```
:1,$s/prefix:\(\([a-z]\)\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)_\)\+\([a-z]\)\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)/???
```

then I have no idea how to fill "???"

We can refer to content in quote of regex by "\1\2" when the quote is unnested, But what to do when the quote is nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally done by two nested substitutes:

```
%s/\v(prefix\:)@<=%([a-zA-Z]%([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+/\=substitute(substitute(submatch(0), '\v[^_]+', '\u\0', 'g'), '_', '', 'g')/
```

Note that you regular expression does not match the example string: “T” in “Th2ere” and “Ther4e” does not match `[a-z]` hence I replaced it with `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: it works, but I still don't know how to refer content in nested quote.

Comment: @XinyuNG When it comes to refering to something there are *no* nesting groups. With `\v(a([bc])+)` checked against `abc` first group (refered as `\1` or `submatch(1)` in `\=expr`) will have value `abc` and second “nested” (`\2`/`submatch(2)`) will have value `c`. There is no way you can get the value `b` out of it even though the second group did match `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Nested matches are still counted `\1`, `\2`, etc., counting open braces from the left; those inner matches that do not apply are simply empty.

Tip: To avoid needless capture groups, use `\%(...\)` for those parts that you don't need to capture. Regexp engines like Perl's allow named captures, which make this more understandable, but Vim doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1):

An entirely different approach is to `split()` your string at the "_" characters to get a list.  Apply `substitute()` to each string in the list with `map()`, then `join()` the pieces together:

```
:s/prefix:\zs.*/\=join(map(split(submatch(0), '_'), 'substitute(v:val, ''^[a-z]'', ''\u&'', '''')'), '')
```

This is rather long, but it has very simple regular expressions.

```
:help split()
:help substitute()
:help map()
:help join()
:help /\zs
```